# How can I look at the database of my application on a non-rooted phone

Tags: android

I have installed my android application (with debug on) on my non-rooted Nexus phone.
My question is how can I look at the database created by my application?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149438/tool-to-see-android-database-tables-and-data

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into this and unfortunately there's no practical way to do this. This is because you can't get access to the files on a non-rooted phone.

This is why whenever I need to access the database, i just fire up the emulator since you can easily get access to the database and even make changes on the fly and see how it effects the app.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do that but if its your own application you can actually go through the tedious way of exporting your database files to the sd card heres a utility method I came out with to help with that..

Change the string "/data/net.rejinderi.yourpackagehere/databases/yourdbnamehere.db" to fit your application, create an instance of the AsyncTask and call execute on it. that simple.

Be sure to include the permissions of using the external storage though..

Good luck. :)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExportDatabaseFileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private final ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private Context context;

    public ExportDatabaseFileTask(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
       this.progressDialog.setMessage("Exporting database...");
       this.progressDialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... args) {
       File dbFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/net.rejinderi.yourpackagehere/databases/yourdbnamehere.db");

       File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
       if (!exportDir.exists()) {
          exportDir.mkdirs();
       }
       File file = new File(exportDir, dbFile.getName());

       try {
          file.createNewFile();
          this.copyFile(dbFile, file);
          return true;
       } catch (IOException e) {
          return false;
       }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
       if (this.progressDialog.isShowing()) {
          this.progressDialog.dismiss();
       }
       if (success) {
          Toast.makeText(context, "Export successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else {
          Toast.makeText(context, "Export failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }

    void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
       FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
       FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
       try {
          inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
       } finally {
          if (inChannel != null)
             inChannel.close();
          if (outChannel != null)
             outChannel.close();
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

for debug purposes you can programatically copy db file(s) from internal phone memory to external (SD card). they're just a files after all